# What is my missing operator in my query expression?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

First off, I am very new with Access so apologies if this is super basic, but I am running into an issue with my query and I do not know what the problem is.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT [Long Hours].[STORE NUM]
FROM [Long Hours]
ORDER BY [Long Hours].[STORE NUM];
```

The query runs properly, but when I try to sort the data I am given this error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expresson 'STORE NUM'.

I know this error is often caused by not bracketing fields that contain spaces, but my fields are bracketed, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

[image]

Comment: Is `[Long Hours]` a table or query?

Comment: [Long Hours] is a table

Comment: Does this query work? `SELECT [Long Hours].[STORE NUM] FROM [Long Hours] ORDER BY 1;`

Comment: The query runs and I am able to view the results, but same issue as before. When I go to Datasheet view and click the header to sort, I get that same error message.

Comment: So the error you reported does not happen when you first open the query.  You only get the error when attempting to apply a sort via the UI methods with the query already opened in Datasheet View.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. Maybe this is something with the UI method? I don't really see what the problem is with the query itself.

Comment: I'm puzzled, too.  :-(  With the query in Design View, open its property sheet.  Make sure it says "Selection type: Query Properties" just below the "Property Sheet" header.  Is there anything among those properties (Filter, Order By, etc.) which looks suspicious?

Comment: I don't believe so... I added a picture of my property sheet for you

Comment: I don't see a problem there, either.  If you can share a copy of your database, I'll see if I can figure this out later.  I have to leave for a while now.

Comment: Try removing the order by in your query. The property order by on load should handle it on its own. Fill in the "Order by" property with the column name. If using the UI, let the UI properties handle it.

Comment: Here is an interesting bit for you, When I run this: `SELECT [Long Hours].[STORE NUM], [Long Hours].Hours
FROM [Long Hours], [Long Hours] AS [Long Hours_1];` I am able to sort Hours, but still not STORE NUM.

Comment: What data type is the `STORE NUM` column?

Comment: the data type is text.

Comment: Just to rule out any unusual query settings: Does the problem persists if you create a new query in SQL view and simply paste the SQL code there?